# How to set SASS variable using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass

I want to set a global variable in css using sass css.
That global variable must be set using javascript.
How to set variable using javascript or any other method
I have use root css but its not supported for IE browser.
Following is my css

```
$mainbgimage: image url;
.page-title {
padding: 0;
min-height: 200px;
background-image: $mainbgimage;
}
```

Comment: It's not possible to set a SASS variable from JS

Comment: Share your code so we can tell you a workaround of what you want to achieve, as what you ask is impossible to do.

Comment: You just can set a CSS dynamically with javascript but scss don't. SCSS need an transpiler to pare it into CSS.

Comment: There is a way around it i just found out. You can duplicate your current sass stylesheet then change variables in that duplicate and load different stylesheet within javascript.

Answer (score 0):

SCSS and the like are preprocessed languages.
They bring features (like variables) to make it easier to develop and maintain your styles.
However those features are not supported by vanilla CSS and you need to run the preprocessor (SASS) to generate the CSS that the browsers support.

The resulting CSS has no variables hence you cannot change them with client side javascript directly.

But fortunately you have plenty of options for dynamic styles.
I'd always recommend toggling CSS classes like so:

```
document.getElementById('elementId').classList.add('specialStyleClass');

/* ... */

document.getElementById('elementId').classList.remove('specialStyleClass');
```

You can even set element styles directly from javascript:

```
document.getElementById('elementId').style.color = 'red';
```